# How to unpack a tag.gz file without having 2x free space?

Tags: linux, compression

I have about 1 million small files, that take up about 20 GB. I need to upload them to a host that only has 23 GB free space. I would prefer compressing the files locally to increase the transmission speed (would it work btw?), but I don't think I will have enough free space to unpack the file (there is no need to keep the archive). Is there any compression format that would allow decompressing the file with that little free space?

Comment: Just using `rsync` would probably be enough (even without compression unless the network is _really_ slow). Creating an archive and then unpacking it would take longer, probably even if you somehow created it through a pipe directly to the remote system and read from the pipe with `tar -x` (all files would have to be read and written regardless).

Comment: You can ask rsync to use compression over the networ, or if it uses ssh you can ask ssh to use compression.

Comment: @meuh, so `rsync -avz` should do the trick?

Comment: `ssh user@remotehost 'cd target/directory && tar -zx' < to-send.tar` or `ssh user@remotehost 'tar -zx --directory=target/directory' < to-send.tar`

Comment: stream it, Don't save it: that is un-compress as it arrives, but don't save it. `tar` supports reading from standard in.

Comment: Yes, `rsync -avz` will show at the end *...speedup is 4.5* or some number which shows by what factor the data was reduced. But try it on a subset of files first, because if you have very small files rsync compresses each file, and this may not be as good as `tar czf - fromdir | ssh remote 'tar xzf - -C todir'`, where tar does the compression of the stream.

Comment: from the target machine you can run an ssh script that runs the tar on the server with the files and pipe the output of that ssh command to a local tar command that reads from stdin and dumps the files: something like ssh <host> 'tar -czf - <file names>' | tar -xzf -